# Error with check.form

Tags: javascript, html

I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined at
>   HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):20)

this is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Music Stream | Login</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="headphone.png">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans"         rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
    <h1>Login Page</h1>
    <div id="loginform">
    <form name="login">
        <p>Username</p><input type="text" name="userid"/>
        <p>Password</p><input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
        <br>
        <input id="btnl" type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
        <input id="btnl" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript">
        function check(form) { /*function to check userid & password*/
            /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
            if(form.userid.value == "admin" && form.pswrd.value == "admin") {
                window.open('adminp.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
            }
            else if(form.userid.value == "user" && form.psword.value == "user") {
                window.location = 'start.html';
            }
            else {
                alert("Error Password or Username")
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i fix this error
check it with F12 on my site of you can fix it: 
 http://gamemaster2030.github.io/index.html

and i cant login with any username and password i have set in the js the admin page is not a page it must be created please login with user and user

Comment: Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7tvkL5k8/ Works here.

Answer (score 0):

most possibly the default behaviour of form submit just skips your script

try to add this attribute to your form

```
<form onSubmit="return false;"
```

this way the form wont submit and reload the page and your logic comes in place.

Not to mention your approach is absolutely insecure because everybody could read your password in the source code. Also you can straight open 'adminp.html' without any login

Answer (score -1):

hi check your else if(form.userid.value == "user" && form.psword.value == "user") you no use psword fileds pls change to if(form.userid.value == "user" && form.pswrd.value == "user")